# JS counter write to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

Is there any way I can use this JS second counter, to write to mysql:

```
var counter = 0;
setInterval(function () {
  ++counter;
}, 1000);
```

Can I export it as a variable and then use that variable to write to mysql?

What I'm attempting to do is save the time the user was on the page.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Look for [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)

Comment: @m_pro_m I'm not familiar with AJAX, can u be more specific?

Comment: His AJAX is a link to w3schools to learn about it - which is very specific. It's the technology used to send information to a server without redirecting the user to any other page. With jQuery, $.ajax, $.get, or $.post are very useful for this.

Answer (score 0):

To help solve your ajax part (need jquery):

```
$.ajax({
         type:'POST',
         url: "yourfile.php",
         data:{
             "foo": filename // to add more variables you add on the spot after filename but remember the last one variable you send shouldn't have a comma
         }
});
```

on the receiving end (php):

```
<?php
    $filename = $_POST["foo"];
?>
```

basically ajax is used to send data to a php script.
Javascript is a language that is used in client side and can't write to MYsql. The code above will help you send data to your script. Your php script will run once it recieves the data through AJAX

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write a bit of back-end php to handle ajax query from your front-end javascript.

Your JS may look like this:

```js
function ajaxRequest(data) {
  var xmlHttp = null;

  xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlHttp.open("POST", "path/to/back-end.php", true);
  xmlHttp.timeout = 1000;

  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) { //DONE
      //success
      console.log("Successfully sent to back-end.php");
    }
  };

  xmlHttp.send(data);
}
```

You can refer to http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp for more information.

Then your php will retrieve the body of this POST request and insert it to mysql database accordingly.